# How to hide cmd console when excute .exe program compiling by Nuitka?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, cmd, nuitka

I used this (python -m nuitka --follow-imports program.py) command to compile my script using Nuitka . It made an .exe file which worked quite well for me other than --onefile commands , as they were showing me import error. But here the problem is , a cmd console opens up of my .exe file after is start it, then my tkinter gui console shows up. I tried to use .pyw file to compile my script, but it didn't help me. I need help to shutdown or hide that cmd console window which pops up for my .exe file.

Comment: If you look into `nuitka` web site, you should find the command line option `--windows-disable-console`.  Or use `python -m nuitka --help` to get available options.

Comment: Thank you , --windows-disable-console this command worked. But after i shared to another pc . the exe wasnt working